# How to make ordered lists collapsed by default in org mode

Tags: org-mode, cycling

Suppose, we have this org file:

```
* Header1
** Header1-1
** Header1-2

* Header2

   1. Item 1

      1. Item 1-1
      2. Item 1-2

   2. Item 2
```

When I open it by default it looks like this:

```
* Header1...
* Header2...
```

Unordered items are collapsed. But when I open Header2, all the elements of the ordered list items are visible, so I see this:

```
* Header2

   1. Item 1

      1. Item 1-1
      2. Item 1-2

   2. Item 2
```

I can cycle visibility by moving the cursor to `Item 1` and clicking `<tab>`. Is it possible to make the ordered lists collapsed by default?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is not specific *only* to ordered lists.
This behaviour is related to [plain lists](http://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html) (ordered, unordered, description) in general.

> For more details, see the variable *org-cycle-include-plain-lists*. If this variable is set to *integrate*, plain list items will be treated like low-level headlines.

To the point:

```
(setq org-cycle-include-plain-lists 'integrate)
```

should fix your problem for all *org* files (if I understand your issue correctly).

If you want more granular control then you can also set this per directory, file, etc.

Also FWIW - items belonging to the same plain list *must* have the same indentation on the first line.

Comment: The integrate setting can lead to strange effects when switching visibility
to children - best read the doc string associated with the 'org-cycle-include-plain-lists' variable.

Comment: In my experience, this setting makes expanding top-level headlines significantly slower. Does anyone have a fix for this?