# How to make Org lists show collapsed by default?

Tags: org-mode

Simple question:  How to make list show collapsed by default?
It's very annoying to find the lists uncollapsed and visually not pleasing everytime I open a buffer full of lists.

Another thing is that lists must be collapsed one by one... so it'd be handy to know a function or a #+STARTUP property for the buffer in question that would fix this for the lists appearing in that buffer.

[image: Non-collapsed list]

[image: Collapsed list]

Comment: Please, have you checked this [thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5544/how-to-make-ordered-lists-collapsed-by-default-in-org-mode)?