# org mode fold lists like headers

Tags: org-mode

I would like my org mode lists to behave like headers.
That is, cycling (exploding) a header containing a list will result in a list of folded items, each which can be cycled.

I figured out how to do this six months ago (I think while reading orgmode.pdf cover to cover) and it looks like I didn't write it down to remind myself how I did it. I just need to set some variable a value mentioned in its docstring.

Someone who knows please tell me.
Thanks for giving me answers for years. Use emacs every day.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for `org-cycle-include-plain-lists`. Also, this related post should help: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5544/how-to-make-ordered-lists-collapsed-by-default-in-org-mode

Comment: ^ @kozina-adjacent ty